# Static random member still outputting the same number each time

Tags: c#, random

I have a static random member that when I use rand.next(1,2) I always get 1. I don't understand why.

```
    static Random rand = new Random();

    private static void Attack(Player player, Monster monster)
    {
        var pDamage = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(player.Weapon.Attack * monster.Armor.DamageRedux));
        Console.WriteLine("You strike the {0} for {1} damage.", monster.MonsterName, pDamage);
        monster.Health -= pDamage;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var hitRoll = rand.Next(1, 2);
            Console.Write("{0}", hitRoll);
        }
        switch (1)
        {
            case 1:
                var mDamage = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(monster.Weapon.Attack * player.Armor.DamageRedux));
                Console.WriteLine("The {0} swing back and hits you for {1} damage.", monster.MonsterName, mDamage);
                player.Health -= mDamage;
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("The {0} swings wildly at you and misses.", monster.MonsterName);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: switch (1) is always going to be 1...

Comment: If you only have two cases then use an if statement. A switch might be slower in this case

Comment: Because a switch is a compiled to a map of pointers where each case equals a function. It's not always faster and not always the best choice. The call to each case takes more instructions than it would take for a simple compiled if/else.

Answer (score 0):

The max value is exclusive when the min value is inclusive. Visually:

```
minValue ●—— value ——○ maxValue
```

or as an expression

```
minValue <= value && value < maxValue
```

Here is the documentation for `Next`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I totally didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the values sent to the Next() method:

```
var hitRoll = rand.Next(1, 3); // Generates a value between 1 and 2
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that `rand.Next(1, 3)` generates a random value between 1 and 2. It generates a value between 1 and 3, it's just that the lower bound is inclusivem and the upper bound is exclusive.